VR movies generation using VMD
I am trying to generate 3D/VR movies using VMD and I am having trouble. While following the general instructions here: https://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Research/vmd/minitutorials/vrmovies/ ,
I can set the environment variables in the Tkconsole, but nothing changes in the OpenGL display to reflect the environment changes. I am unsure if it is an issue with the version of VMD I am using (1.9.4a57 for macOS), or if I am working on macOS, or if I am missing instructions. Any help on steps to make VR movies with VMD would be greatly appreciated!

The changes, although active, are not shown on the OpenGL display. You'll only see the effects when rendering. The same is true for other rendering options, e.g. outlines and shadows.
Using the same version of VMD you mentioned, I managed to create a VR image by issuing the following commands to TkConsole:

set env(VMDOPTIXIMAGESIZE) "2000 2000"
set env(VMDOPTIXEQUIRECTANGULAR) "1"
set env(VMDOPTIXAOMAXDIST) "1"
set env(VMDOPTIXSTEREO) "1"

and then rendering with Tachyon-LOptiX (both internal and interactive rendering seemed to work just fine).
